# Pick random columns from a DF and perform an operation

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I am working with a df that contains 4000 columns and 17560 rows. Im performing an experiment in which I need to pick 5 random columns from the data, and multiply the value of its cell by a random number between 0.08 to 0.12. The multiplication has to be done only in specific intervals. Additionally, the operation is repeated 100 times, and every time is repeated it has to be with 5 different columns, that is why the columns need to be picked randomly. At the moment I am using the following code:

```
 interval = int(17560/365)    
 for k in range(1,100):
  rand_nums= np.random.uniform(0.08,0.12)
  df[34:45,:] *= (1-rand_nums)


  for i in range(1,interval):
    rand_nums = np.random.uniform(0.08,0.12,5)
    df[i*48+34:i*48+45,:] *= (1-rand_nums)
```

The code works, because in the second for loop I specify the number of columns, however, every time I do this operation, it picks the first 5 columns. My question is:

Is there any way to pick random columns every time I do this operation without including another for loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns= list(range(100)))

# Put these inside your loop
rand_cols = np.random.permutation(df.columns)[0:5]
df[rand_cols]
```

The code `np.random.permutation` shuffles all the column names and now any slice of this list will be a random selection of column names.

The code `df[rand_cols]` results in a selection of a subset of `df`, so if you multiply that by some number e.g. `df[rand_cols] = df[rand_cols] * 2` only the values in rand_cols will be modified.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, I do not understand how to know which columns were selected. Also by writing df[rand_cols] it means it will only perform the operation in the random columns or should I modify the code to something like this df[i*48+34:i*48+45,rand_cols] *= (1-rand_nums)?

Comment: Updated the answer to try and explain better.